# GetLocalResourceObject with NVelocity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, nvelocity

How can I load a .resx file with GetLocalResourceObject when using NVelocity? I'm using ASP.NET MVC with mvccontrib nvelocity viewengine and sharp-architechture.

I've hardcoded every possible virtualpath I could think of (eg. ~/Home/index.vm.resx) but everyone fails. I've also tried with ExpressionBuilderContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you calling GetLocalResourceObject? Calling it from a controller action will not work, because an action has no real association to any view file (e.g. /Home/Index.vm). A local resource will **only** work from within the actual view (`/Home/Index.vm`).

Also, make sure the .resx files are placed within App_LocalResources folders in each of the "view folders" (e.g. `/Home/`)

- /Views/Home/Index.vm
- /Views/Home/App_LocalResources/Index.vm.resx

Hope this was of some help Anders, if not, buzz me on Messenger ;-)